# How to connect database GUI like Navicat to Atlas MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, navicat

I was able to get my connection string:

`mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.xyz.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

I am entering above URI to the URI window in Navicat connection wizard but connection does not work.
My IP is added to whitelist.

Thanks for any help.

[image]